# Send multiple notifications to a user on specific time

Tags: node.js, redis, scheduled-tasks

So I have database of users which have a `reminderTime` field which currently is just a string which looks like that `07:00` which is a UTC time.

In the future I'll have a multiple strings inside `reminderTime` which will correspond to at which time the user should receive a notification.

So imagine you logged into an app, set a multiple reminders like so `07:00`, `15:00`, `23:30` and sent it to server. The server will save those inside a database and run a task and send a notification at `07:00` then at `15:00` and so on. So later a user decided that he will no longer wants to receive notifications at `15:00` or change it to `15:30` and we should adapt to that.

And each user has a timezone, but I guess since `reminderTime` is already in UTC I can just create a task without looking at timezone.

Currently I have a `reminderTime` as `number` and after client sends me a `07:00` I convert it to seconds, but as I understand I can change that and stick to `string`.

All my tasks are running with `Bull` queue library and `Redis`. So as I understood the best scalable approach is to take `reminderTime` and just create notifications for each day at a given time and just run the task, the only problem is that should I save them to my database or add a task to a queue in `Bull`. The same will be for multiple times.

I don't understand how should I change already created tasks inside `Bull` so that the time will be different and so on.

Maybe I could just create like a 1000 records at which time user should receive a notification inside my database. Then I create a repeatable job which will run like every 5 minutes and take all of the notifications which should be send in the next couple of hours and then add them to a `Bull` queue and mark it that it was sent.

So basically you get the idea, maybe it could be done a little bit better.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have really a lot of users, you could simply create a schedule-like table in your DB, which is simply a list of `user_id | notify_at` records. Then, run a periodic task every 1-5 minutes, which compares current time and selects all the records, where `notify_at` is less than the current time.

Add the flag `notified`, if you want to send notifications more than once a day to ignore ones that was already sent. There is no need to create thousands of records for every day, you can just reset that flag once a day, e.g. at 00:00 AM.

It's ok that your users wont recieve their notifications all at the same time, there could be little delays.

The solution you suggested is pretty much fine :)

Comment: Let's suppose that I have a lot of users how should I proceed then and what will change?

Comment: I can imagine that at some moment you wont't be able to process all of your users by the time you will need to send another notification (e.g. you send first at 13:00, next one at 13:01, having one minute to notify all of your users). Well, you can scale it with queues that run in parallel, taking some small chunks of users at once. I won't help you with the exact names, because I'm not so familiar with Node and Bull, but if you have some PHP backend, you can probably make it with RabbitMQ

Comment: I wanted to do something like I create notifications inside Postgres for the next month, then I use queue job with Redis or RabbitMQ where I'll will get a current day and add one day to it. Then I'll run a Postgres query to get all of the users to which I'll need to send a notification in that date range and then I'll create jobs for it and set a flag that it was sent or smth like that. Then I hope that I will not run into that issue until some moment.